# Flush every entry, older then X Days in Database

Tags: mysql

is there a way to configure a Database, so it flushes every entry, that is older than a certain amount of time?
I want to use this for a sort of "recycling bin" Database, just so you can recylcle data, if you accidently deleted it, but it should not be a full backup, so it should contain entries only for a few days, or hours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [MySQL partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html) for this.

Also take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html). I've read that versions 5.5 and later allow you to do direct partitioning using non-numeric values such as dates and strings, so that might make life a bit easier for you.